# Running a Command that will run on every computer

Tags: vb.net

I have this code which gives me all of the information I need regarding tasks, information etc. I have it all shelled into a VB program and I want to be able to run this from one computer and have it return the data from all computers on the domain.

I am lost as to what to add next.

```
      Dim sCommand As String
      'all processes here, ipconfig, java info, etc etc
      sCommand = "java.exe -version2 > C:\Info.txt && ipconfig >> C:\INfo.txt"         
      Shell("cmd.exe /c" & sCommand)
```

I have script that will list all users on the domain, can I implement that or is there an easier way?

Edit: If I could search the entire domain for a specific file that would work too.

At the moment I just need all the data returned to a text file, I am not worried about it being sorted, or how long a process like this would take.

thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do one of two things.

1) You could use WMI to get both the network config off the remote machines and execute a process on the remote machine.

Or

2) You could use [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) to kick off a command on a remote machine and pipe that out. I personally wouldn't use shell to execute a command as it's pretty poor really. If I was going to kick off a process locally I'd use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx), and use [StdOut](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_run_dos.html) to grab the output from the shell, parse it to give you something you can work with instead of piping the output to a file locally and then reading it later.

*EDIT*
So you want to do all this from one central location? If you don't want to use PSExec, you'll have to use [WMI to create a process on a remote machine](http://weblogs.asp.net/steveschofield/archive/2006/06/06/WMI---start-a-process-on-remote-machine-passing-credentials_2E00_.aspx) to run the java.exe, but you can't redirect the output, you'll have to pipe to a file and read the file in another step.

Comment: I have thought about PSExec but I must do all of this within. I cant have stuff running with it. (IE the downloaded PStools Kit with PSexec. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Yes. I want to run this from one computer on the domain. In simple terms I want every computer on the domain to run those commands, or a VB program that I have written that pulls all that information. And I want all the results from each computer written out to a textfile

Comment: Forgive me if this is rude, but are you familiar with writing subs and functions and creating classes in .net?

Comment: very little everyone has to start somewhere

Comment: Indeed, we all start at the beginning, have a read of this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973814.aspx - Learning to use classes and methods early on will save you a lot of time doing things wrong before you do them right. I learned the hard way ;)